# SBT build structure for a mono repository

Tags: scala, sbt

I'd like to use SBT for a build structured around a single Git repository with tens of projects. I'd like to have the following possibilities from the build:

1. One-click build/test/release of all projects in the build.
2. Define and apply common settings for all the projects in the build.
3. Define project-specific settings in the project sub-directories, keeping the root of the build clean.
4. Project should be able depend on each other, but...
5. Most of the projects will not depend on each other in the classpath sense.
6. Some of the projects will be the SBT plugins that should be included into other projects (but not to all of them).

Now with these requirements in mind, what should be the structure of the build? Because of requirement 3, I can't just go with a single `build.sbt` in a root of a build, because I don't want to put all the projects settings there, since it will be a lot of text, and every change in a single project will be reflected on the top level.

I've also heard the usage of `*.sbt` files both for root project and sub-projects is error-prone and not generally recommended ([Producing no artifact for root project with package under multi-project build in SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747296/producing-no-artifact-for-root-project-with-package-under-multi-project-build-in), or [How can I use an sbt plugin as a dependency in a multi-project build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482604/how-can-i-use-an-sbt-plugin-as-a-dependency-in-a-multi-project-build), [SBT: plugins.sbt in subproject is ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122761/sbt-plugins-sbt-in-subproject-is-ignored) etc.). I've tried only simple multi-projects builds with `*.sbt` files on different levels, and it just worked. Which pitfalls do I need to keep in mind if I'll go for a multi `*.sbt` files approach, given the requirements above?

Answer (score 13):

Ok, since no one have posted anything so far, I've figured I post what I've learned from doing mono repository with SBT so far.

Some facts first: our SBT build consists of 40+ projects, with 10+ common projects (in the sense that other projects depend on them), and 5 groups of projects related to a single product (5-7 projects in each group). In each group, there's typically one group-common project.

## Build organization

We have the following build structure:

1. One main `build.sbt` for the whole build.
2. One `build.sbt` per project.
3. Several local SBT plugins in `project` directory.

Let's talk about each of these items.

### **1. Main `build.sbt`**

In this file, the general build structure is defined. Namely, we keep cross-project dependencies in there. We **don't** use the standard `commonSettings` approach, as in:

```
val commonSettings = Seq(scalaVersion := "2.12.3", ...)
...
val proj1 = (project in file("p1")).settings(commonSettings)
val proj2 = (project in file("p2")).settings(commonSettings)
...
```

This would be too wordy and easy to get wrong for a new project. Instead we use a local SBT project that automatically applies to every project in the build (more on this later).

### **2. Per-project `build.sbt`**

In those files, we generally define all the project settings (non-auto plugins, library dependencies, etc.). We **don't** define cross-project dependencies in these files, because this doesn't really work as expected. SBT loads all the `*.sbt` files in certain order, and project definition in every build overrides the previously found ones. In other words, if you avoid (re-)defining projects in per-project `*.sbt` files, things will work well. All the other settings can be kept there, to avoid too much clutter in main `build.sbt`.

### 3. Local SBT plugins

We use a trick to define SBT auto-plugin in `<root_dir>/project/` directory, and make them load automatically for all the projects in the build. We use those plugins to automatically define the settings and tasks for all the projects (for things like Scalastyle, scalafmt, Sonar, deployment, etc.). We also keep common settings there (scalaVersion, etc.). Another thing we keep in `<root_dir>/project/` is common dependencies versions (not in a plugin, just pure `*.scala` file).

## Summary

Using SBT for a mono repository seems to work, and has certain advantages and disadvantages.

**Advantages**: It's super easy to re-use the code between products. Also common SBT stuff like Scalastyle, scalafmt, etc. is defined once, and all new projects get it for free. Upgrading a dependency version is done in one place for all the projects, so when someone upgrades the version, he or she does this for all the projects at once, so that different teams benefit from that. This requires certain discipline between teams, but it worked for us so far.

Another advantage is use of common tooling. We have a Gerrit+Jenkins continuous integration, and we have a single job for e.g. pre-submit verification. New projects get a lot of this machinery pretty much for free, again.

**Disadvantages**: For one, the build load time. On top 13" MacBook Pro it can easily last 30+ seconds (this is time from starting SBT to getting to SBT's command prompt). This is not that bad if you can keep the SBT constantly running though. It's much worse for Intellij refreshing the build information, where it can take around 15 *minutes*. I don't know why it takes so much longer than in SBT, but here's that. Can be mitigated by avoiding refreshing the Intellij unless absolutely necessary, but it's a real pain.

Yet another problem is that you can't load an individual project or group of projects into Intellij IDEA. You are forced to load the build of whole mono repository. If that would be possible, then, I guess, Intellij's situation could have been better.

Another disadvantage is the fact that one can't use different versions of same SBT plugin for different projects. When one project can't be upgraded to a new plugin version for some reason, the whole repository has to wait. Sometimes this is useful, that is, it expedites maintenance work, and forces us to keep projects in maintenance mode up to date. But sometimes for legacy projects it can be challenging.

## Conclusion

All in all, we have worked for a around a year in this mode, and we intend to keep doing so in the foreseeable future. What concerns us is the long Intellij IDEA refresh time, and it only gets worse as we add more projects into this build. We might evaluate alternative build systems later that would avoid us loading projects in isolation to help with Intellij performance, but SBT seems to be up to a task.

Comment: Wish I would have seen this a month ago! After doing all the research from scratch we came up with a nearly identical solution for an sbt monorepo. One optimization we made to reduce the build time issues you were talking about was only rebuilding the projects that changed by using an artifact cache and an autoplugin that diffs our source code between commits. So future people definitely look at that approach. Sadly this doesn't help with the intellj issues though.

Comment: @gnicholas cool, thanks for sharing! I have some ideas about Intellij performance as well (cached update in sbt 1.0 should help), but haven't come to try them so far. Is your code publicly available? Would be nice to have a look at it.

Comment: My day job so sadly not open sourced. I'm trying to open source the sbt plugin but it will take a bit. The plugin was heavily inspired by Akka's pull request builder plugin they use in their project here if you are curious: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/project/ValidatePullRequest.scala#L235

Comment: Hello there. Five years later, do you still use the same patterns, were you able to improve it? Not need to say that I have a Hughe interest in that discussion and would like to have more details. Can you provide a sample structure (like an anonymised tree of your monorepo)?

Comment: Hi @gervais.b! I've not been using sbt since 2019, and don't have access to that code base anymore. But I've been keeping some cursory attention to the sbt development, and from what I know, this answer still stands. There might have been performance improvement related to BSP/Metals, but I don't have any concrete numbers to prove that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an update on this discussion 5 years later.

For those who understand french, there is this presentation from ScalaIO 2019:

- François Sarradin: **SBT monorepo et livraison**, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nT8YhC5iRco

There is also this video that is not specific to Sbt but give good tips that was recommanded in that gitter discussion: https://gitter.im/sbt/sbt?at=63584746f00b697fec5b7184

- Gil Tayar: **FOUR PILLARS AND A BASE: THE NUTS AND BOLTS OF A MONOREPO**  jsday 2020, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIGFyv1KuGI