# SBT: how to exclude one sub-project from one aggregated task

Tags: scala, sbt, multi-project, subproject

I have a bunch of sub-project that I define as follows (actually generated by a `project/meta.sbt`):

```
lazy val Top = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(common, p1, p2, tests, scripts)
  .dependsOn(common, p1, p2, tests, scripts)
lazy val common = project
lazy val p1 = project.dependsOn(common % "compile->compile;test->test")
lazy val p2 = project.dependsOn(common % "compile->compile;test->test")
lazy val tests = project.dependsOn(common % "compile->compile;test->test")
lazy val scripts = project
```

AFAICT (so maybe that's wrong), both the `aggregate` and the `dependsOn` at the top make sense: the first to run tasks in all sub-projects, and the second to make it convenient to debug stuff.

Now, the thing is that `tests` contains just a bunch of tests, and `scripts` is a script that is used as a publishing step -- so I need to somehow make it avoid making jar files *only* for them.  I still want `compile`/`test`/etc to be aggregated including them.

My understanding from the docs is that this should be done by setting the `aggregate` key in `Top`, and indeed adding something like

```
  .settings(aggregate in clean:= false)
```

prevents `clean` from being aggregated -- but I want to do that for `package` and I don't want to drop it completely, just not package those two sub-projects.  Using something like `aggregate in (tests, packageBin)` is my best guess, but that doesn't seem to make an impression on SBT: looks like `packageBin` is wrong, and also combining it with `tests` doesn't work.

Is that possible?  Actually, given that SBT is just a tiny bit overengineered, it's always possible, so rephrase: How can I do that?

### Update:

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25653777/128595) I found a workaround -- add:

```
.settings(Keys.`package` := file(""))
```

to the definitions of subprojects that shouldn't be packaged.  That works for avoiding generation of jar files, but it's obviously not an answer for the actual question (which I'm probably going to run into again).

Comment: I'm having the exact same question. Did you ever find a real answer?

Comment: @akauppi: not really, but with the update I mentioned I managed to get around the problem...